# prettier - how to not make each angular attribute on a single line?

Tags: html, angular, prettier

I am in the process of adding `prettier` to my angular project. I am writing the settings into the `.prettiercc` file. When I run it, it changes my HTML, sometimes doubling the lines though unnecessary. For instance, it changed

```
<p-fileUpload #upload class="p-d-inline" name="name" mode="basic"
              [auto]="true" customUpload="true" accept=".json"
              chooseLable="upload thing" chooseIcon="pi pi-folder-open"
              (uploadHandler)="load($event.files, upload)"
>
```

to

```
<p-fileUpload
  #upload 
  class="p-d-inline" 
  name="name" 
  mode="basic"
  [auto]="true" 
  customUpload="true" 
  accept=".json"
  chooseLable="upload thing"
  chooseIcon="pi pi-folder-open"
  (uploadHandler)="load($event.files, upload)"
>
```

However, this seems somewhat excessive, and the original division had some logic to it.

Is there a way to configure prettier for angular/html so it divides lines by length (so if I exceed max, it'll break it up) but not so specifically as by each attribute?

Comment: I'd go through the options offered by prettier and see if there's something useful (https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html).

Comment: thanks, I have gone through them and read this article, I do not think it is possible unfortunately. https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html